# Whats the difference between DelegatingFilterProxy and GenericFilterBean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

- `DelegatingFilterProxy` enables you to use a Spring Bean as a servlet filter. So you can use the spring context inside the filter, inject other beans and so on. It extends `GenericFilterBean` in order to gain this functionality.
- `GenericFilterBean` enables you to do the same.

Both classes seem to claim to provide the same functionality in the end. Both classes seem to be able to be wired directly in the `web.xml`. The code of `DelegatingFilterProxy` seems to be just a thin layer of indirection.

But why is this even necessary, where you could just extend `GenericFilterBean` instead? Why, for example, does Spring Security use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` in order to call the `FilterChainProxy`, although the latter already extends `GenericFilterBean`?

Answer (score 1):

> It extends `GenericFilterBean` in order to gain this functionality.

I think I'd word that differently. According to [`GenericFilterBean`'s JavaDoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.java#L54):

```java
/**
 * This generic filter base class has no dependency on the Spring  
 * org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext concept. Filters usually 
 * don't load their own context but rather access service beans from the 
 * Spring root application context, accessible via the filter's 
 * ServletContext
 **/
```

Note also from `GenericFilterBean`'s JavaDoc:

```java
/**
 * This filter leaves actual filtering to subclasses, which have to implement 
 * the Filter.doFilter method.
 **/
```

Or, IOW, `GenericFilterBean` picks up `init-param`s, registers them as Spring bean properties, and applies those properties to the filter. `init-param`s are limited in their capacity and also `doFilter` still needs implementing either way.

This is where `DelegatingFilterProxy` comes in. It looks up a bean of type `Filter` from the application context and proxies to it in its own `doFilter` method. This proxy allows applications to specify a bean of type `Filter` that relies on Spring's lifecycle instead of the servlet container's.

You can see this detailed in [`DelegatingFilterProxy`'s JavaDoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.java#L45):

```java
/**
  * This approach is particularly useful for Filter implementation with 
  * complex setup needs, allowing to apply the full Spring bean definition 
  * machinery to Filter instances.
  */
```

*NOTE*: Spring Boot applications can alternatively publish beans of type [`FilterRegistrationBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container.servlets-filters-listeners.beans) to specify both the underlying filter, its order and dispatcher types.

> Both classes seem to be able to be wired directly in the `web.xml`

What gives you this impression? Given that `GenericFilterBean` is `abstract`, I'm not clear on how it could be referenced in a `web.xml` file. The Servlet container would not be able to construct it.

> does Spring Security use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` in order to call the `FilterChainProxy`

[Yes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.2/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-delegatingfilterproxy).

Spring Security chooses to use the `Filter` API instead of inventing its own. Because of that, it fits nicely inside the purpose of `DelegatingFilterProxy`.  (You can imagine how limiting it might be for folks to configure Spring Security though `web.xml` `init-param`s alone, for example.)

Hypothetically, if Spring Security had decided to create its own filter-like API, it would have its own implementation of `GenericFilterBean` that implements `doFilter` differently.

> although the latter already extends `GenericFilterBean`

I think this part of your question is asking "couldn't `FilterChainProxy` just be specified as a filter to the servlet container since it implements `GenericFilterBean`?". And the answer is ["no"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.2/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-delegatingfilterproxy). From Spring Security's docs:

> Another benefit of `DelegatingFilterProxy` is that it allows delaying looking `Filter` bean instances. This is important because the container needs to register the `Filter` instances before the container can startup. However, Spring typically uses a `ContextLoaderListener` to load the Spring Beans which will not be done until after the Filter instances need to be registered.

Why does it extend `GenericFilterBean`, then? Most Spring filters extend `GenericFilterBean` because it allows more flexibility for applications to use them like building blocks. Like its JavaDoc says:

```java
/**
  * A handy superclass for any type of filter.
  */
```